# Alternatives to grip tape on a longboard

Tags: finishing

Making my first longboard, and I'd like to put some art on top of it. On most skateboards (like Carver for example - see pic 1) grip on the top side of the deck is achieved by using a grip tape. On other boards though (like Globe for example - see pics 2, 3) some other technique is used. It looks like it's grains of sand + glue or lacquer, which is great because you can apply colorful art on top of it.

Any one has an idea how to create such grip on the longboard's deck? How to create grains? What type[s] of glue to use?

Thanks

**Carver with grip tape (not what I need)**
[image: Carver, using grip take (pic 1)]

**Globe, colored, with grip that is sort of see-through (what I want to achieve)**
[image: Globe, using mysterious grip technique]

**Globe, closer look**
[image: Globe, closer look]

Answer (score 4):

Try a good paint shop, there are numerous non-slip aggregate additives for most finishes. If you intend to use lacquer or varnish on the deck they shouls have something.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a more suitable method, you can purchase clear grip tape. Of course it's a little opaque due to the grit it contains, but I had a deck covered in clear tape as a youngster with stickers underneath.

Comment: I found [this guy on YouTube](https://youtu.be/hjy82PJbeh0) who, while being a little 'out there', will tell you all about clear grip tape

Answer (score 1):

You could try using spray adhesive (such as the one below) along with sand.

I had a similar application for this where I sprayed the adhesive on to a board and then covered the area with an abundance of sand. After the glue dried the excess sand simply fell off.

I think this idea could work for what you are trying to do if you were to use a translucent fine sand.

[image: Adhesive Picture]

Comment: Ok, gave it a try on the weekend. With the same spray glue too. It didn't stick like it does on my Glove board, and could be relatively easily removed with fingers. Guess I'm missing an ingredient.